# How to create a aspx form

Tags: vb.net

I wanna create a aspx form where it should connect with a HTML form and how should i display it in vb.net..

also when click the  link, the form should fill with data automatically where the data should retrieve from microsoft sql database and display it without any error...

Comment: That's nearly all web applications. Any ASP.NET tutorial you find on Google should help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Question is kind of broad one. But you can use asp.net form view to show the data from the database and you can access it from the server side code(VB.Net).
http://www.learn-asp.net/asptutorials/FormView.aspx here is a good article for you.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand very well! but I guess you want to create a ASP.NET page with vb.net.right?

If I'm correct, steps are depend on your version of Visual studio but the only thing you need is create website project!
Second question:You should First retrieve data from your database
Here is good article: [Click](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2559).

If I misunderstood, let me know!